# Unable to scrape a name from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script in python to fetch a name which is populated upon filling in an input in a webpage. Here is how you can get that name -> after opening that webpage (sitelink has been given below), put `16803` right next to `CP Number` and hit the search button.

I know how to grab that using `selenium` but I'm not interested to go that route. I'm trying here to collect the name using `requests` module. I tried to mimick the steps (what I can see in the chrome dev tools) within my script as to how the requests is being sent to that site. The only thing I can't supply automatically within `payload` parameter is `ScrollTop`.

[Website Link](https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx)

This is my attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx"

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(URL)
    cookie_item = "; ".join([str(x)+"="+str(y) for x,y in r.cookies.items()])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    payload = {
        'StylesheetManager_TSSM':soup.select_one("#StylesheetManager_TSSM")['value'],
        'ScriptManager_TSM':soup.select_one("#ScriptManager_TSM")['value'],
        '__VIEWSTATE':soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")['value'],
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value'],
        '__EVENTVALIDATION':soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")['value'],
        'dnn$ctlHeader$dnnSearch$Search':soup.select_one("#dnn_ctlHeader_dnnSearch_SiteRadioButton")['value'],
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$ddlMemberType':0,
        'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber': 16803,
        'ScrollTop': 474,
        '__dnnVariable': soup.select_one("#__dnnVariable")['value'],
    }

    headers = {
        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBhsR9ScAvNQ1o5ks',
        'Referer': 'https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx',
        'Cookie':cookie_item,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
    }
    res = s.post(URL,data=payload,headers=headers)
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    name = soup_obj.select_one(".name_head > span").text
    print(name)
```

When I execute the above script I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

> ***How can I grab a name populated upon filling in an input in a webpage using requests?***

Comment: there are more cookies passing than showing in your script I think. Also, your first two selectors retrieve empty string literals though looks like you can grab those values from elsewhere (at least one for sure). Those values remain stable across requests though maybe not over a longer period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is the data encoding. I've noticed that you've set the Content-Type header to "multipart/form-data" but that is not enough to create multipart-encoded data. In fact, it is a problem because the actual encoding is different since you're using the `data` parameter which URL-encodes the POST data. In order to create multipart-encoded data, you should use the `files` parameter.

You could do that either by passing an extra dummy parameter to  `files`,

```
res = s.post(URL, data=payload, files={'file':''})
```

(that would change the encoding for all POST data, not just the `'file'` field)

Or you could convert the values in your `payload` dictionary to tuples, which is the expected structure when posting files with requests.

```
payload = {k:(None, str(v)) for k,v in payload.items()}
```

The first value is for the file name; it is not needed in this case so I've set it to `None`.

Next, your POST data should contain an `__EVENTTARGET` value that is required in order to get a valid response. (When creating the POST data dictionary it is important to submit all the data that the server expects. We can get that data from a browser: either by inspecting the HTML form or by inspecting the network traffic.)  The complete code,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx"

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    payload = {i['name']: i.get('value', '') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber'] = 16803
    payload["__EVENTTARGET"] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch'
    payload = {k:(None, str(v)) for k,v in payload.items()}

    r = s.post(URL, files=payload)
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    name = soup_obj.select_one(".name_head > span").text
    print(name)
```

---

After some more tests, I discovered that the server also accepts URL-encoded data (probably because there are no files posted). So you can get a valid response either with `data` or with `files`, provided that you don't change the default Content-Type header.

It is not necessary to add any extra headers.  When using a `Session` object, cookies are stored and submitted by default. The Content-Type header is created automatically - "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" when using the `data` parameter, "multipart/form-data" using `files`. Changing the default User-Agent or adding a Referer is not required.

Comment: Your answers are always clean, concise and flawless @t.m.adam. I almost thought that it might not be possible this way. Let's wait few more days as long as the bounty is on in order for others to come across your solution as well.

Comment: I think you won't berate If I'm a little more greedy @t.m.adam. I found this `res = s.post(URL, data=payload, , files={'file':''})` very interesting and I'm willing to comply in future cases. However, this `files={'file':''}` seems to have come out of nowhere. Could you suggest me in comment how can I use this? I just used like `res = s.post(URL,data=payload,files={'file':''}),headers=headers)` which might not be the case. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry the comma was a typo. The `{'file':''}` dictionary is a dummy parameter and you could use it to multipart-encode your data. If a value (non-empty dictionary) is passed to `files` then all POST data are multipart-encoded (both `data` and `files`). So yes, you could use a dummy parameter in `files` if you don't want to convert the values of `payload` to tuples.

Comment: @MITHU There is a Clear button that clears the form's content and it seems if you submit this value the form isn't processed. If you delete the `'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$Clear'` key your second script will work as well. You can detect useful (or unwanted in this case) values if you compare your data, one by one,  with the data of a successful request.

Comment: Yes, it does work now. You have always been a great teacher to me @t.m.adam. Btw, this is how I got it working `payload = {item['name']:item.get('value','') for item in soup.select('#form1 input[name]') if '$Clear' not in item['name']}`.

Comment: @MITHU Yes, that's even better! See you around!!

Comment: Hi @ t.m.adam, hope you are doing well. Every time I face any issuse, I look for your availability to seek help. This is [my new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211184/cant-grab-results-from-next-pages-using-post-requests) in which I get stuck solving a particular problem. Thanks in advance for your generosity to look into this problem.

Comment: @MITHU Sorry but I can't figure this out either. I'll give it one more try later tonight but I'm afraid I won't be able to help you with this question.

Comment: Don't bother @t.m.adam, you have always been a great help to me. Thanks.