# Can't grab results from next pages using post requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape `the name of different institutions` from a directory. It is necessary to perform post http requests in order to scrape state wise content. To be clearer - the result I'm after populated upon filling in the two fields:

1. country: `United States`
2. state: `Alabama`

[Website link](https://hub.nacacnet.org/institutionmemberdirectory)

My following script can fetch the content from it's first page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://hub.nacacnet.org/institutionmemberdirectory"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {item['name']:item.get('value','') for item in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id162:j_id163:j_id164:j_id165_1:j_id198:Country'] = 'US'
    payload['j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:j_id162:j_id163:j_id164:j_id165_1:j_id634:State'] = 'AL'
    res = s.post(url,data=payload)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in sauce.select(".card-heading span"):
        print(item.text)
```

However, trouble comes up when I try to fetch the result from the next pages as there are 5 more pages to traverse to get all the results.

When I hit the next page button and see the parameters in chrome dev tools, I can discover this new field `pageNum: 2`, so I added it to the payload to get the result from the next page but I'm still having the content from it's first page.

> ***How can I get the content from next pages as well?***

Btw, selenium is not an option I would like to cope with.